# Get my latest Twitter post with PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to make a simple site that uses php and the Twitter API to write out my latest post from twitter. I found a tutorial showing me how to get my timeline (or last 20 posts) in xml format, but can't figure out how to print out **just** the latest post, and **just** the text of it (not the time, date, etc that come with the xml/rss/etc).

My code looks like this

```
<h2 id = "latest">
    <?php
        var $username='myusername';  
        var $password='mypassword'; 
        var $responseInfo=array();

        function latest_status($format='json',$id=null) {
            $request = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.'.$format;
            if($id) {
                $postargs = "id=$id";
                return $this->process($request,$postargs);
            }
            return $this->process($request);
        }

        echo latest_status("json");
    ?>
</h2>
```

And it's returning this:

> [{"contributors":null,"created_at":"Tue
>   Feb 16 19:56:08 +0000
>   2010","in_reply_to_user_id":null,"source":"API","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"truncated":false,"user":{"notifications":null,"profile_link_color":"0000ff","description":"","verified":false,"profile_background_tile":false,"created_at":"Tue
>   Feb 16 01:16:15 +0000
>   2010","profile_background_color":"9ae4e8","profile_image_url":"http://s.twimg.com/a/1265999168/images/default_profile_1_normal.png","time_zone":"Hawaii","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"e0ff92","followers_count":0,"screen_name":"whisperingweb","lang":"en","friends_count":0,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"87bc44","statuses_count":2,"following":null,"protected":false,"favourites_count":1,"location":"","name":"Chris
>   Armstrong","contributors_enabled":false,"profile_text_color":"000000","id":114608397,"geo_enabled":true,"profile_background_image_url":"http://s.twimg.com/a/1265999168/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","utc_offset":-36000,"url":null},"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"geo":null,"id":9199090048,"text":"Someone
>   was on your
>   website"},{"favorited":false,"source":"web","in_reply_to_user_id":null,"created_at":"Tue
>   Feb 16 18:50:21 +0000
>   2010","geo":null,"user":{"verified":false,"description":"","notifications":false,"profile_text_color":"000000","screen_name":"whisperingweb","profile_background_image_url":"http://s.twimg.com/a/1265999168/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","url":null,"profile_link_color":"0000ff","followers_count":0,"statuses_count":2,"profile_background_tile":false,"created_at":"Tue
>   Feb 16 01:16:15 +0000
>   2010","friends_count":0,"profile_background_color":"9ae4e8","contributors_enabled":false,"time_zone":"Hawaii","favourites_count":0,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"e0ff92","protected":false,"location":"","name":"Chris
>   Armstrong","lang":"en","geo_enabled":true,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"87bc44","id":114608397,"following":false,"utc_offset":-36000,"profile_image_url":"http://s.twimg.com/a/1265999168/images/default_profile_1_normal.png"},"contributors":null,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"id":9196705546,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"truncated":false,"text":"The
>   quick brown fox jumps over the lazy
>   dog"}]

I'm pretty new to php, and completely new to the Twitter API, so would appreciate any help or advice.

**edit: Have changed example from xml to json**

Comment: What is `$twitter` in your code? Do you use an already existing Twitter library to access it? What is `$this` referring to inside of the function (i.e. where is the rest of the class definition)? And what type is the output of that function (check with `var_dump`).

Comment: Ah yea, sorry. I'm using a library I got from here http://brandontreb.com/the-only-twitter-api-php-class-you-will-ever-need/, I just copied and pasted the bits I figured were relevant. Should I just correct my question by removing $twitter->, or would I be better showing the entire library as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use format='json' instead: json_decode($response)[0]['text'].

In this case, use JSON because it has a much more natural mapping to PHP's internal datatypes, which makes it dead-easy to extract the content you want. You *can* still use XML, but you have to iterate over the resulting structure, which is relatively complex.

Comment: Whats the benefit of JSON over XML?

Comment: JSON can be parsed faster than XML *in php*.

Comment: It's a standard you can access directly without caring about parsing the data (which can be quite cumbersome in terms of xml and even more raw html).

Comment: Ok, so I wouldn't need an extra library for JSON like I would with XML? If so, how do I parse JSON directly?

Comment: The following is throwing up a syntax error, don't suppose you can see where the problem is?

return json_decode($this->process($request))[0]['text'];

The error is unexpected '['

Comment: $decoded = json_decode($this->process($request)); 
   return $decoded[0]['text'];

// gives me 
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. Sorry if this is a noob error

Answer (score 2):

That's just your webbrowser displaying the contents of the xml file without tags. You'd need to use an xml library (e.g. simplexml, http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to get the informations you want.

**edit to reflect OP change**

Use the json_decode method (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). The output can be accessed like an array.

For further questions, also, please use the documentation of PHP and google (I got the information about json by googleing "json in php").

Comment: Any tips on how I would implement the library? Is it through the library that I would specify which post, and which elements of it, to display?

Comment: you need to use the functions offered by the simplexml library (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php for a basic tutorial) and just get comfortable with it. I agree with djc though, use the json possibilty, it will spare you a lot of tears.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've changed the example to be json instead of xml. What do I need to add to select just the latest post from the json data?